# How to distinguish between exceptions

Tags: mysql, ruby, exception, mysql2, rescue

I am attempting to create a simple script in Ruby that accesses a MySQL database and runs a query based on user input.

If a user gives bad login information or attempts to `SELECT` `FROM` a table or column that does not exist I would like the user to re-enter *only* the information that is causing an issue instead of having to re-enter all information.

I wish for this code to raise an exception based on what part of the query threw an error:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "mysql2"
require "watir"
require "csv"

Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)
mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "1.2.3.4", :username => "usr", :password => "pass123", :database => "db")

db = "db"

puts "Please enter all `table`.`column` pairs you wish to select from; separated by a comma and space."
tCP = gets.chomp.split(", ")

dynQ = "SELECT "
tCP.each {|pair| dynQ << (db + "." + pair + ", ") }

puts "Please enter the `table` you wish to select from:"
tF = db + "." + gets.chomp

dynQ = dynQ.chop!.chop! + " FROM " + tF + " LIMIT 10;"

report = mysql.query(dynQ)

begin
  report = mysql.query(dynQ)
  report.each {|row| puts row}

  puts "Query Successful!"

rescue Mysql2::Error => e
  puts e.errno
  puts e.error

  puts "Please re-nter all `table`.`column` pairs separated by, ', '."
  tCP = gets.chomp!.split(", ")

  dynQ = "SELECT "
  tCP.each {|pair| dynQ << (db + "." + pair + ", ") }

  tF = db + "."
  puts "Now re-enter the `table` to select `FROM`:"
  tF << gets.chomp!

  dynQ = dynQ.chop!.chop! + " FROM " + tF + " LIMIT 10;"

  retry
end
```

For example, if I `SELECT` from a table or column that doesn't exist, I get this:

```
/Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:107:in '_query': Table 'db.table_dne' doesn't exist (Mysql2::Error)
  from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:107:in 'block in query'
  from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:106:in 'handle_interrupt'
  from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:106:in 'query'
  from file.rb:23:in '<main>'
```

Yet if I am taking that selection from a table that doesn't exist, I get the same exact thing:

```
/Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:107:in '_query': Unknown column 'db.table_dne' doesn't exist (Mysql2::Error)
  from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:107:in 'block in query'
  from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:106:in 'handle_interrupt'
  from /Users/guy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:106:in 'query'
  from file.rb:23:in '<main>'
```

Ideally, I want to `rescue` based on what exception appears in the console and have the user re-enter either `tCP` or `tF` instead of just being given a more general exception.

I looked through the [MySQL2 documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.4.3) without luck.

Comment: Exception is a string. Since there is no difference in classes, you can analyze exception message and do whatever you want

Comment: @nick-roz That helps a lot; but I just found that analyzing the `e.errno` would be easier.  Your comment did point me in the right direction though.

Comment: At no time should you allow an untrusted user to enter any SQL. That's a great way to get hacked. If you kinda trust the user then present the information in a list they can select from so typos and/or ad-hoc queries can't be injected. If your interface is on the command-line then give serious thought to moving it to a web form where you can control that input better, or write and run a lot of code to validate their input _before_ submitting it to the database. Once it hits the database it's too late to protect against malicious SQL. You probably should be using an ORM to help protect your DB.

Comment: Stylistically, in Ruby we don't use camelCase for variables, instead we use snake_case. ItsAReadabilityThing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your attempt:

```
rescue Mysql2::Error => e
  puts e.errno
  puts e.error
```

1. `rescue` keeps your script running
2. `Mysql2::Error => e` takes from the `Error` class and stores in `e`
3. `puts e.errno` `puts` the error number to the console
4. `puts e.error` `puts` the error description to the console

And with that, the following `begin` loop should work for you:

```
begin
  report = mysql.query(dynQ)
  report.each {|row| puts row}

  puts "Query Successful!"

rescue Mysql2::Error => e

  if e.errno === 1146
    puts e.error

    tF = db + "."
    puts "Now re-enter the `table` to select `FROM`:"
    tF << gets.chomp!
  elsif e.errno === 1054
    puts e.error

    puts "Please re-nter all `table`.`column` pairs separated by, ', '."
    tCP = gets.chomp!.split(", ")

    dynQ = "SELECT "
    tCP.each {|pair| dynQ << (db + "." + pair + ", ") }
  else
#   puts e.errno
    puts e.error

        puts "Please re-nter all `table`.`column` pairs separated by, ', '."
    tCP = gets.chomp!.split(", ")

    dynQ = "SELECT "
    tCP.each {|pair| dynQ << (db + "." + pair + ", ") }

    tF = db + "."
    puts "Now re-enter the `table` to select `FROM`:"
    tF << gets.chomp!
  end

  dynQ = dynQ.chop!.chop! + " FROM " + tF + " LIMIT 10;"

  retry
end
```